# Regular expression for fax number validation in a JavaScript registration form

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms, validation

I am a complete newbie when it comes to regular expressions. Even after reading guides about them, I still have a hard time formulating my own. I am trying to get my form to validate the fax number in the +12345678910 format. I have some code, but it allows me to submit mixed numbers and letters, as well as submit data with blank spaces and without filling out the faxnum text box completely. I would strongly appreciate any help with the form and tips on how to become more proficient with regex.

```
var fax = document.registration.faxnum; 
faxval(fax);

function faxval(fax)
{
    var numbers = /[\+? *[1-9]+]?[0-9 ]+/; //Bad regex
    if (fax.value.match(numbers))
    {
        document.getElementById("faxmsg").innerHTML=("Everything is OK.");
        faxmsg.style.color="green";
    }
    else
    {
        faxmsg.innerHTML=("Invalid fax number.");
        faxmsg.style.color="red";
    }
};
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking for a good fax number, not a bad one

Comment: You're using square brackets incorrectly. Try `/(\+? *[1-9])?[0-9 ]+/` instead, perhaps?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage unfortunately this gave me the same results.

Comment: @user3361043 Ah, you need to match the start and end of the string too: `/^(\+? *[1-9])?[0-9 ]+$/`

Comment: You shouldn't put any spaces in the regular expressions! (But if you need to match a space, just use `\s`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a number like +12345678910, try: `\+1[2-9][0-9]{9}`

I assume that the +1 portion is the international number code, 234 is the area code, 567 is the exchange and 8910 is the rest of the number. This pattern would also match a number such as +12125551212.

The first digit of any U.S. or Canadian phone number must be 2 through 9. So we can allow that as the first character (`[2-9]`). Then the rest of the number will be 9 digits long, 0 through 9 (`[0-9]{9}`).

If you want to allow - or . too, you can use: `\+1(|\.|\-)[2-9][0-9]{2}(|\.|\-)[0-9]{3}(|\.|\-)[0-9]{4}`. The `(|\.|\-)` part means "allow no character OR a . character OR a - character."

Comment: I tried your first regex, but my form stopped working completely. Right now I am using squeamish's /^(\+? *[1-9])?[0-9 ]+$/ regex but it still lets me submit incomplete data. I need a solution which restricts the user to +12345678910 format and nothing else.

Comment: If you didn't already, try wrapping it in / pattern delimeters:  `/\+1[2-9][0-9]{9}/` or `/\+1(|\.|\-)[2-9][0-9]{2}(|\.|\-)[0-9]{3}(|\.|\-)[0-9]{4}/`